# Merge object from apply operation to dataframe in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an object from an apply operation and I want to merge it with a dataframe. My understanding is that the object from the apply operation is not a dataframe, and thus not possible to use a merge operation. An approach would be to transform to a dataframe, but I don't know how.

For example, I used the following code to get the first valid index for a dataframe df1:

```
p1 = df1.apply(lambda series: series.first_valid_index())
```

As a result I got the following:

```
AAA   5
BBB   6
CCC   3
```

I want to merge it with the dataframe df2:

```
       val1   val2
Index
  AAA    12     qw   
  BBB    6      te   
  CCC    31     gb
```

so I can get the following:

```
       val1   val2  val3
Index
  AAA    12     qw    5
  BBB    6      te    6
  CCC    31     gb    3
```

When I try type(df1) I get the following

```
   <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How could I do the merge operation? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join aligns on the index.

```
p1.name = 'val3'
>>> df2.join(p1)
     val1 val2  val3
AAA    12   qw     5
BBB     6   te     6
CCC    31   gb     3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and the promptness, it works. Just to add that I found that I can transform the output of the apply operation to a dataframe by using pd.DataFrame(p1) and then I can use a merge operation to merge with the df2. I suspect that join maybe is more efficient in the current setting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should be using merge for combining two dataframe for the specific needs that you describe. I would better suggest the [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) function or the [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method; for example usage refer to the following [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

As a solution for your problem I scratched up a piece of code. If it is a pandas series object you should be able to add it to your dataframe by specifying a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

# Making some definitions
ind = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
cols = ["val1","val2","val3"]
val1 = pd.Series(index=ind, data=[21,22,23])
val2 = pd.Series(index=ind, data=["qw","te","gb"])
val3 = pd.Series(index=ind, data=[1,2,3])
ser = [val1,val2,val3]

# Defining a dataframe using the defined series objects
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=ind, data={cols[i]:ser[i] for i in range(3)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=ind, data={cols[i]:ser[i] for i in range(2)})

# Making a dataframe from first two series objects and adding
# third column
df22 = df2.copy()
print("Test1, Before:")
print(df2)
df22["val3"] = val3
print("Test1, After:")
print(df22)

# Same thing done using join
dfj = df2.copy()
val3.name = "val3" #need name for join
dfj = dfj.join(val3)
print("Test2, After:")
print(dfj)

# same thing done using concat
dfc = df2.copy()
dfc = pd.concat([dfc,val3],axis=1)
print("Test3, After:")
print(dfc)
```